# Impersonating user using Google service account fails (JAVA client)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-oauth-java-client

When i try to impersonate a user in **Google Apps Domain** to authenticate **Google Drive API** using 
**setServiceAccountUser()** i get a response as

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 403 OK { 
>   "error" : "access_denied",   "error_description" : "Requested client
>   not authorized." }

Below is my code :

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                            .setTransport(httpTransport)
                            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID)
                            .setServiceAccountUser("user@domain.com")
                            .setServiceAccountScopes(scope)
                            .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(privateKey)
                            .build(); 
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,null).setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).setApplicationName(AppName).build();
File body = new File();
body.setTitle("Export");
body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
service.files().insert(body).execute();
```

Thanks in advance !

Ram Balaji Subbaiyan .

Comment: If your application access drive, then the scope should be included. Otherwise it throws this error. You can try checking this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035665/gmail-api-service-accounts-return-403-error

Answer (score -1):

The error is thrown because of incorrect service account user

```
 setServiceAccountUser("user@domain.com")
```

The user account mentioned here should have the domain level access. Also try enabling domain level delegation for the service account